# PHP scrape data from website that is loading content as the user scrolls down

Tags: php, scrape

I want to scrape data from a website, but this website is loading content as the user scrolls down. U can see full content (all items) only when u scroll to the bottom of the div.

What is the best way to scrape  all the data from this website ?

Comment: that data is being fetched via ajax. find out the urls being loaded and just hook up to that.